# Which hotel is featured on the cover of Career Paths: Hotels & Catering?

Tags: hotels, identify-this

I just saw this English learning book and was wondering which hotel is this:

[image: hotel]

Comment: A bit more of the building here: https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/787163220/4a4f99e02803611605f7b8a8456abbe9

Comment: Are you sure it is a real hotel?

Comment: Aren't there any credits in the publication that would tell you which hotel this is?

Comment: Interestingly, a reverse image search on Google (using a fragment of the image with jus the building itselff) only turns up that publication.

Comment: It sort of looks like a CGI image.

Comment: I found a more complete image of it on a Africa travel (maybe) book. The windows stop just below what's visible on the Career Paths cover and there are indistinct taxis at ground level. If anyone wants to look: http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.e-reading.club/cover/1033/1033582.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.e-reading.club/book.php?book=1033582&h=700&w=442&tbnid=GtDko0YpfGfFPM&tbnh=283&tbnw=178&usg=__G0QSNEB-YrKMD3I5_xcQr58eddE=&hl=en&docid=T6n0oYdbgM-9nM

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Nairobi Safari Club hotel](http://www.nairobisafariclub.com/).

[image]
<sub>(source: [nairobisafariclub.com](http://www.nairobisafariclub.com/img/slider-home/slider_01.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Just...how? Been there? :-O

Comment: This is how http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31840418#31840418

Comment: @motoDrizzt Hat tip to mkennedy. The picture with the taxi and the truck made me think Africa was a good bet, so extracted a portion of the image and fed to google images with "hotel" "africa" in it. Scrolled down a few pages and spotted it